# 0x800a138a - JavaScript runtime error: Function expected

Tags: javascript, asp.net, textbox, onchange

I have a TextBox in my ASP.NET page. A javascript function is triggered when the value inside the textbox is changed.

Any idea why I get this error?

Error:

> 0x800a138a - JavaScript runtime error: Function expected
>   [image]

ASP.NET code:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="entryRates" Width="80" onChange="return showAlert(this);" runat="server" CssClass="TextBox" />
```

JS code:

```
<script type ="text/javascript" >
   function showAlert(obj) 
   {
      if (document.getElementById("rType").value!="HLDR") 
      {
        iput = obj;
        //numberic value (positive or negative)
        if (isNaN(iput.value))
        {
            alert("The entered rate is not a number");
            return false;
        }
        //today's rate
        tdrate=iput.value 
        //yesterday rate
        if (document.all.item("rType").value!="OTHR") 
        {
            ydrate = iput.parentElement.parentElement.childNodes(2).firstChild.innerText; 
        }
        else
        {
            ydrate = iput.parentElement.parentElement.childNodes(4).firstChild.innerText; 
        }
        //alert ("yesterdaycode = "+ydrate);
        trptg = 1.25  //thresholdPercent
        //alert("thresholdPercent = "+trptg);

      if (tdrate.length == 0)
         {
         tdrate=0
         }

      if (ydrate.length == 0)
         {
         ydrate=0
         }
      totchg = (((tdrate / ydrate) - 1) * 100)

      if (totchg < 0)
         {
         totchg = (totchg * -1)
         signchg=1
         }
      else
         {
         totchg = totchg
         signchg=0
         }

      if (totchg != 100 & totchg > trptg)
         {
         if (signchg==0)
            {var s = "" + Math.round(totchg * 100) / 100}
         else
            {var s = "-" + Math.round(totchg * 100) / 100}
         alert("% Change = "+s)
         }
        }
      }  
      </script>
```

Comment: `childNodes` is a read only property, it's not a function, and it does not accept arguments ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.childNodes` is an "array-like object". One accesses its elements via square brackets:

```
ydrate = iput.parentElement.parentElement.childNodes[2].firstChild.innerText;
```

---

Side note: Don't use `document.all`. It's a proprietary extension. Use a standard method, such as `document.getElementById()`, as you're already doing at the top of your function.

Answer (score 0):

Recently i had the same javascript runtime error, which happend only in IE. The problem was in one of my function names. I guess the name was reserved in IE or something. I have just renamed it and the problem was fixed. Just in case, here is the name of the problematic function:

```
function start(){
}
```

renamed to:

```
function startInstallation(){
}
```